# How to find coordinates of several points on the page using TikZ or \pdfsavepos or some other means?

Tags: positioning, tikz-positioning, pdfsavepos

I need to have the coordinates of several word-ends on a page typeset with XeLaTeX, with respect to the lower left corner of the page. For example, I would need a macro `\getposition{label}` that could be used in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla
blabla blabla\getposition{abc} blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla\getposition{def} blabla blabla blabla
blabla blabla blabla\getposition{ghi} blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla
blabla blabla.\getposition{jkl}
\end{document}
```

As a result, I would need, in the log file or some other file, a list of labels and coordinates (in sp) like this:

```
abc:1562354sp,78944895sp
def:2562153sp,78944895sp
ghi:1326435sp,64253484sp
jkl:645435sp,13264356sp
```

I tried with `\pdfsavepos`, `\pdflastxpos`, `\pdflastypos` and `\message` but it writes only zeros in the log file (because it only knows the information in shipout time, but then how do I keep track of more than one “last positions”?).

I can, of course, go into the XDV file and calculate the position of each point, but this means playing around with DVI stacks and calculating the width of all horizontal elements until the marked point. I know there is utility `dvipos` that does that, but it doesn't seem to work with XDV files.

Is there some other way to get the information directly, maybe using TikZ or some other means?

Comment: you can use zref-savepos, it offers the \zsavepos{label} command.

Comment: Thank you Ulrike, do you have an example? (the zref documentation is cryptic…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\getposition#1{%
\pdfsavepos
\write\@auxout{%
  \gdef\string\X#1{\the\pdflastxpos}%
  \gdef\string\Y#1{\the\pdflastypos}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla
blabla blabla\getposition{abc} blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla\getposition{def} blabla blabla blabla
blabla blabla blabla\getposition{ghi} blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla
blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla
blabla blabla.\getposition{jkl}

\ifdefined\Xabc abc is at (\Xabc,\Yabc)\else\typeout{re-run latex}\fi

\ifdefined\Xghi ghi is at (\Xghi,\Yghi)\else\typeout{re-run latex}\fi

\end{document}
```

You write them all to the aux file, and pick them up on the second run

Comment: Thank you so much David. This is very useful!

Comment: zsavepos and tikzmark are both essentially this, but looking more like `\label` and `tikz` respectively. tikzmark especially useful if you want to use the coordiates in a tikz drawing as it sets up the corresponding tikz pic nodes rather than just dumping raw coordinate data @yannis

Answer (score 1):

`zref` offers an user interface of David's code (the values can differ on your system if you use another default paper format):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\begin{document}

some text\zsavepos{label1}  

some longer text\zsavepos{label2}


text one is at (\zposx{label1},\zposy{label1}) 

and text two is at (\zposx{label2},\zposy{label2})

\end{document}
```

[image]